# Using Dataset and table adapters for Service Based Database in Visual Studio 2017 and VB.net

Tags: vb.net, tableadapter

I am trying to create a Windows form with a self contained DB. I added a Service Based DataBase. I then created a Dataset. My table is simple:

Example:
columns are: Model (PK), Part1, Part2, Part3............

I want a combobox on my for to be able to select the model, and another combobox to select the desired part then return the number. You pick Model 740, and Part1 and the return is part1 part number.

The issue is that I need the select Statement in the tableadapter query builder to show something like this.

SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE Model = ? (Paramter from ComboBox1) AND parameter (Part1 From Combobox2 Will be a ***Column Name***)

I can't figure out how or if it is even possible to have a parameter in after the select.

Table is built like this:
[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bf4kv.png

Comment: *Part1 From Combobox2 Will be a Column Name* - column names cannot be parametrized in the "usual" way

Comment: You're better off having a `Models` table as the parent Model table, a `Parts` table as the parent Parts table, and then a separate `ModelParts` table with ModelID and PartID. Then you could pass a query the ModelID and return all Parts in `ModelParts` belonging to that ModelID.

Comment: Thank you. I eventually realized that. I can be a little slow.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I got it figured out

'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'CSDataset.CryoSeries' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
Me.CryoSeriesTableAdapter.Fill(Me.CSDataset.CryoSeries)

```
    'Pulling Data From Table Adapter       
    Dim db As New DataTables.CSDatasetTableAdapters.CryoSeriesTableAdapter
    Dim result = db.GetData
    Dim Model As String = CBmodel.Text.Trim
    Dim Part As String = CBPart.Text.Trim

    TBresult.Text = result.Rows(0).Item(Part)
```

Comment: Mmm.. it's not exactly like that.. there are ways to make life a lot easier..

Comment: Well, if you are happy; I am happy. Although, I think the database design might be flawed. How many parts does each model have? Do some models have, say, 5 parts and other models have 7 parts?

Comment: Lots of models and parts.  In my new job I thought I would try and build an app to have all the tables. I got some tables built for one group, and created datasets of the tables. One table of model numbers to bind to a combo box, another table for part names to bind to a combo box. Both save to a variable and search the last table to return a part number. Go the most part it is working. I do find getting the datasets associated to different forms aggravating.